# Possible with Chrome extension? Add list of words to custom dictionary?

Tags: google-chrome, dictionary, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to build a Chrome extension, that when installed or updated, automatically adds a list of words to the user's custom dictionary?

We use a custom-designed Chrome extension at my company, and essentially I'm looking for an easy way to synchronize everyone's spellchecking.

(it would be messy to have everyone download the custom text file and move to C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Custom Dictionary.txt, or whatever the location is)

Thanks!

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like this is something you would want to handle during system administration, i.e. when first installing the operating system(s). Just host the custom dictionary somewhere and have it fetched when you set up each new work station as part of the install script

Answer (score 1):

The best way to create your extension is probably with content scripts that detect user input fields and edit their input on the fly.

Chrome 45 and below does not have an API for dictionary access. Doesn't look like it's planned for either.
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index

However, if you can find the path they use to their dictionary, and if it's not just bytecode or the likes *(SPOILER: it probably is)*, - then you can probably append your dictionary to it. Use the fileSystem API to edit it:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem

Also, if you choose the fileSystem-path instead of the content-script-path then know that extensions cannot use the fileSystem API. You need to create it as a packaged app.
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps